# Convert a string to a date in C++

Tags: c++, string, date

I know this may be simple but being C++ I doubt it will be. How do I convert a string in the form 01/01/2008 to a date so I can manipulate it? I am happy to break the string into the day month year constituents. Also happy if solution is Windows only.

Answer (score 18):

```
#include <time.h>
char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
```

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out without using `strptime`.

Break the date down into its components i.e. day, month, year, then:

```
struct tm  tm;
time_t rawtime;
time ( &rawtime );
tm = *localtime ( &rawtime );
tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
tm.tm_mon = month - 1;
tm.tm_mday = day;
mktime(&tm);
```

`tm` can now be converted to a `time_t` and be manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

For everybody who is looking for `strptime()` for Windows, it requires the source of the function itself to work. The latest NetBSD code does not port to Windows easily, unfortunately.

I myself have used the implementation **[here](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/tree/master/src)** (strptime.h and strptime.c).

Another helpful piece of code can be found **[here](http://pastebin.com/LpRgTPNG)**. This comes originally from Google Codesearch, which does not exist anymore.

Hope this saves a lot of searching, as it took me quite a while to find this (and most often ended up at this question).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  int year, month ,day;
  char str[256];

  cout << "Inter date: " << endl; 
  cin.getline(str,sizeof(str));

  replace( str, str+strlen(str), '/', ' ' );  
  istringstream( str ) >> day >> month >> year;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo->tm_year = year - 1900;
  timeinfo->tm_mon = month - 1;
  timeinfo->tm_mday = day;
  mktime ( timeinfo );

  strftime ( str, sizeof(str), "%A", timeinfo );
  cout << str << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works well.. With just a little modification this should be the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Why not go for a simpler solution using boost

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost::posix_time;    
ptime pt = time_from_string("20150917");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the boost library(cross platform)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

int main()
{    
std::string strTime = "2007-04-11 06:18:29.000";
std::tm tmTime = boost::posix_time::to_tm(boost::posix_time::time_from_string(strTime));
return 0;
}
```

But the format should be as mentioned :)