# String to Time Conversion

Tags: c++

In C++ is there any way to extract a time from a string?

```
CString str;
str="17:18:58,9187120";
```

Is there any utility for converting this string in to a Time variable?

Comment: For those confused about the 9187120 part (like I was), he's using comma as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

see this question: 
[Convert a string to a date in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The POCO library has a DateTimeParser class which might be helpful:
http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.DateTimeParser.html

Answer (score 0):

Not in C++ or its standard library. C++ barely handles its own complexity, it's too much to ask for anything that isn't common to all cultures, platforms, galaxies and vegetables.

For now you can do with Boost's [string conversion functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.dates_as_strings).