# Inverse of strftime()

Tags: c++, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a string to a date in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c)

I have a date/time string in a standardized format (RFC 1123) that I would like to convert to a unix timestamp to compare it with another date/time.

I can convert a timestamp to a string by using strftime with the magic format string

```
"%a,%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"
```

The problem is, I need to do the inverse of this, and turn the formatted string back into a timestamp. What is the best way to do this?