# Convert Date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there any method in MFC to convert date in the format (yyyy-mm-dd) to (dd-mm-yyyy). The date is given as an input ,where the user type the date in yyyy-mm-dd format . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *know* the input string is in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, then you can do a simple string rewrite of the form:

```
out[0] = in[8];
out[1] = in[9];
out[2] = '-';
...
```

If the input string is not formatted that nicely, then you will actually need to parse the date string, which is a harder problem.

The standard way to do that is using strptime(), as discussed in:

[Convert a string to a date in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c)

where the format string would look like "%Y-%m-%d".

Once you have the date, you could print it using something like:

```
printf("%.4d-%.2d-%.2d", tm->tm_year, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday);
```