# how to convert string to date in c++?

Tags: c++, datetime, date

How to covert a string to date and time object in c++ using standard libraries?

Here is my string

```
string input_time = "071215"; //071215 represents 7th December 2015
```

The `input_time` needs to be converted to date object so that I can compare it with date object.

```
bool dateExpired = (input_time < now);
//where now is current date time

if(dateExpired) printf("Expired");
else printf("Not expired");
```

Comment: Since each part of the string is fixed (I guess), then it's easy to extract relevant data and put into a `struct tm` which can be used to get a `time_t`.

Comment: The locale is also important. Where I live it means 15th December 2007.

Comment: Are you stuck with that format, or could you use a standard one, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601?

Comment: @juanchopanza I am stuck with that format. Cant use the standard format

Comment: I also don't think that the locale provider a format which results in "071215" for the date. It will probably provide a format which results in "07.12.15" but not the format you require but I did not check this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a date in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c)

Comment: @ all i have used substring and achieved it. Didn't find any other things useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the c function `strptime`.  If you want a c++ way you can look into the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_objects)

Comment: i dont have access to use boost library

Comment: Yeah, just use strptime then and convert the result to the format you need. I fear you need to check for the right format depending on the locale yourself (see my other comment)

Answer (score 1):

For serious work with dates and time I would suggest [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time.html) and its [IO facilities](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.time_input_facet).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact format, just extract the fields as substrings and run them through an [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/) to change the strings to numbers.

```
#include <strstream>

// . . .

string dayString = input_time.substring(0, 2);
istringstream iss(dayString);
int day;
iss >> day;

// . . .
```