# Converting http date header string to time_t

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, time-t

I want to convert the http header field "Date", which is returned to me in the format
"Wed, 07 Mar 2012 09:58:26 GMT", into a `time_t` value.

I'm not sure if there's a standard format for this field in the http headers.

I saw this: [parsing of date/time from string (boost?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786201/parsing-of-date-time-from-string-boost),
but I don't know if I can make a facet for the format I mentioned.

Also, I need the functionality to be portable.

I could easily parse it by myself, but I hope there's a better, quicker and safer way.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c

Comment: @Rolle No, it is not a duplicate. It's about a different format.

Comment: @Itzuke: strptime can be used for about any format