# DateTime Validation as 25-Jul-2012 15:08:23

Tags: c++, windows

I am using below method to validate Date.
How to format month in string ?

```
bool CDateTime :: IsValidDate(char* pcDate) //pcDate = 25-Jul-2012 15:08:23
{
    bool bVal = true;
    int iRet = 0;
    struct tm tmNewTime;   

    iRet = sscanf_s(pcDate, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", &tmNewTime.tm_mon, &tmNewTime.tm_mday, &tmNewTime.tm_year, &tmNewTime.tm_hour, &tmNewTime.tm_min, &tmNewTime.tm_sec);
    if (iRet == -1)
        bVal = false;

    if (bVal == true)
    {
        tmNewTime.tm_year -= 1900;
        tmNewTime.tm_mon -= 1;
        bVal = IsValidTm(&tmNewTime);
    }
    return bVal;

}
```

Comment: fyi, the `struct` in `struct tm tmNewTime;` is redundant in C++.

Comment: You mixed up "tm_mon" and "tm_year" in your sscanf_s statement.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c ?

Comment: Are you asking about how to do the actual validation, or about how to do the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Using [strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html):

```
#include <time.h>
char *str = "25-Jul-2012 15:08:23";
struct tm tm;
if (strptime (str, "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm) == NULL) {
   /* Bad format !! */
}
```

Comment: I Have included <time.h > bit it is saying strptime  identifier not found

Answer (score -1):

The C++11 way of doing this is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    std::cout << "Now is " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S") << '\n';
}
```

**Note:** The stream I/O manipulator `std::put_time` is not implemented fully in all compilers yet. GCC 4.7.1 does not have it for example.

Comment: The question is about validation of a date given as string, not about streaming out a date as string.

Comment: @JakobS. To quote from the question: "How to format month in string ?" The OP _states_ he want to validate a date, but _asks_ about formatting.

Comment: Ok, you are right - the title does not really reflect the question.