# Convert string to date: strptime identifier not found

Tags: c++, windows, string, visual-studio, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strptime() equivalent on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows)

I'm trying to convert a string to date. `strptime` taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308399/279982) does exactly what I want. However when I try to use it in my code the compiler complains about it:

> error C2065: 'strptime' : undeclared identifier

I have included `time.h` header. I'm using visual studio 2003, also tried 2008.
Is this really a standard function? Is there another function I could use without having to install additional libraries like boost?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3137634/279982 This solved it.

Answer (score 3):

`strptime` is not standard C or C++; it is Unix.  If you're on a
non-Unix machine, it *may* be present, but more likely, you'll
have to find an open source for it, and install it yourself.
(In the case of Visual Studio, a lot of Unix specific functions
are available, but with an underscore in front of the name.  I
don't know if this is the case of `strptime`, but you might try
`_strptime`.)

Comment: Nopes, still not available. Thanks for the response.