# cocos2D-X c++ convert string to Date

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am looking for a method in which i can convert a String to datetime object. I see cocos2d-X dosent contain a NSDate class. Can anyone please help me ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can try CCTime. There  is a function in CCTime gettimeofdayCocos2d()

struct cc_timeval begin;

            virtual float GetElapsedTime(){
                    struct cc_timeval now;
                    CCTime::gettimeofdayCocos2d(&now,NULL);
                    return CCTime::timersubCocos2d(&begin,&now)/1000;
            }
```