# Cross platform string date to unix time in C/C++

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-platform, datetime-format

I found a solution for Windows:

```
istringstream ss_finish("2014-March-02 01:00:00");
ss_finish >> get_time(&t, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S");
time_t finish = mktime(&t);
```

But this is not compilable under Linux with gcc because `get_time` is not yet implemented (gcc 4.9)

I also found a solution for Linux based on `strptime` but this is not compilable under Windows because `strptime` is not recognized by the VS compiler.

Is there a cross-platform way to achieve this task?

I could do some `#define`s and check for the OS but maybe there are some other functions. And I wouldn't like to use `boost`'s date-time functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a date in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c)

Comment: The above code does compile if you use libc++ (ships with clang) rather than the gnu libstdc++.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Convert a string to a date in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308390/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-c)
2. resenting boost (and doing so for a very specific and well implemented task) == reinventing the wheel

Comment: That is not an answer, it should have been an 'exact duplicate' flag, or a comment indicating as much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ctime>`

You might want to check this out: [updated link](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1048383636&id=1043284392&utm_source=newletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=fiftyeighth-followup&fb_action_ids=352523478174767&fb_action_types=og.recommends&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%5B10150140330826519%5D&action_type_map=%5B%22og.recommends%22%5D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D)